# Line passing through another point before connecting to node d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The link between two nodes enter as a straight line , i want the line to bend at a point and then move to that node . How can i do ? 
i dont need a curve , basically a line passing through one point  and then moving towards the other node.

I use

```
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                            return d.source.x;
                        })
                        .attr("y1", function (d) {
                            return d.source.y;
                        })
                        .attr("x2", function (d) {
                            return d.target.x;
                        })
                        .attr("y2", function (d) {
                            return d.target.y;
                        });
```

Comment: The D3 way to do this would be to have data for the separate point that you want to move the line through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use svg path.

```
    path.attr("d", function (d) {
        var sX = d.source.x, sY =d.source.y;
        var tX = d.target.x, tY =d.target.y;
        var mX = (d.source.x+d.target.x)/2+45, mY =(d.source.y+d.target.y)/2+45; //Third point
        return "M "+sX+","+sY+" L"+mX+","+mY+" L"+tX+","+tY;
    });
```